# Technical about extending Mongoose model and model instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, oop, mongoose, ecmascript-6

Sorry for the newbie question, but for ages now what I was doing is something like this:

```
var newUser = new User();
global.models.User = mongoose.model('User', User.schema);
```

And inside my User class I have a methods object, with functions for the model. So what I was doing to "transfer" the methods from the class to the model was then (after the loading above), loop through the User and add the methods. Like so:

```
for (let method of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(newUser))) {
    if (method == 'constructor')
        continue;
    let method = newUser[method];
    global.models.User[method] = method;
}
```

Now this works, but I feel like this is a completely wrong approach. I basically want to extend and add the class methods to the model.

Also, is it possible to add methods to each *instance* of a class? For example, a method like `userInstance.logOut()`?

Sorry for the newbie question, I just feel like I'm not doing it right.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't believe `let method = newUser[method];` really works.

Comment: @Bergi it actually does :P

Comment: What environment are you executing this in, how do you transpile the ES6? This *should* throw a `ReferenceError` because of the temporal dead zone.

Comment: @Bergi I am using Babel to transpile it but that is not my issue. My question is technically how can I "inject" methods to a mongoose model, and how to inject methods to each instance of this model.